# Fail to unzip file from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unzip

i ran this command `wget -qO - https://pastebin.com/raw/KXHyPjG0 | bash` but it giving me this error message
`.ZIP.or sample-zip-file.zip sample-zip-file.zip`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPZDt.jpg)

*pastebin code*

```
printf "\033c"
echo "======================="
echo "Download zip..."
wget -q https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-zip-file.zip
echo "Unziping..."
unzip sample-zip-file.zip
echo "======================="
```

Comment: The output from your wget command has DOS newlines, not UNIX ones.

Comment: Also, from a security perspective, any teaching resource that tells you to run `curl | bash` or `wget | bash` should be trashed.